# Theme for Code Block doesn't work properly in Confluence 5.1

Tags: confluence

I created 2 Code Block elements in Confluence 5.1.

**First attempt**:

1) Code Block | language = java

2) Code Block | language = java | theme = DJango

```
Block       Actual              Expected
-------------------------------------------------
first       DJango theme        Confluence theme
second      DJango theme        DJango theme
```

**Second attempt:**

1) Code Block | language = java | theme = FadeToGrey

2) Code Block | language = java | theme = DJango

```
Block       Actual              Expected
-------------------------------------------------
first       Confluence theme    FadeToGrey theme
second      Confluence theme    DJango theme
```

In the "Preview" area from the creation window I see the expected result, but in the main Preview window / after Save window I see the actual result.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an [old bug](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONF-29390) for the `{code}` macro. The last theme specified in a `{code}` block is applied to all code blocks on the page.